# Fixing stringing within <80% flow print out is weak

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-cr-10, stringing

Here are the details:

- Creality CR 10-S5
- BLTouch leveling sensor
- Micro Swiss Direct Drive filament upgrade kit
- Bed is 66 °C.

I tried dozens of temperatures starting at 205 °C and going all the way down to 180 °C pretty much 1 °C at a time. The present temperature of 188 °C seems to generate a higher stickiness to the bed than other temperatures.

I have also adjusted the flow rate down to 47% and that, although it did help with the stringing, didn't fix it completely and made the whole print super weak.  I have discovered going below 80% is structurally a bad idea.  I wouldn't mind having it at 90% either.

I am trying different retraction speeds and distances now currently testing 5 mm and 70 mm/s retraction.  Previously I tried 4 mm with 60 mm/s and it didn't help.

Using a lower filament flow rate (about <60%) did prevent it from going all the way across at approx 50 mm/s, but alas <60% is too weak structurally. And didn't solve it completely.  The tips had a Y-shaped split top on both sides with the one side of the Y being straight as it is part of the tower.

Any suggestions to rid me of this are welcome.  Reminder flow rate below 80% is too weak, and 188 °C is preferred.

[image: 3D printed retraction tower showing stringing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture looks like classic Cura misbehavior - it's skipping retractions that need to happen because it's done "too many" already. You should be able to confirm this by looking at the gcode in an analyzer that shows retractions or watching the print. Set "Minimum Extrusion Distance Window" to 0 to fix the problem.

You should not be reducing flow at all, and certainly not by more than a few percent. Put it back to 100%.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with Cura - it has a lot of settings with wrong defaults that most users don't even know exist... but once you configure it well, it does a great job.

Comment: Do you have any other settings suggestions I should watch out for?

Comment: Combing might be such a setting.

Comment: Yeah, in my opinion "Max Comb Distance With No Retract" should be set to a very low value just large enough to make it so moves between successive lines of top/bottom fill don't need retraction - something like 0.8 - 1.2 mm. This in turn kinda 'requires' turning on "Zig Zaggify Infill" unless you have really high speed retractions.